# ASP.Net c# - URL Parameter weird behaviour

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting

I'm doing some URL changing to add some id values onto the end when certain components are clicked by the user.

So for example, when I'm logged into my AdminCP I have a list of user accounts which can have various things done to them, like modify the information or delete the user accounts.

The ASP.NET page i'm using is designed off a Master Page. That Master Page is also part of the Global Master page. So, like a nested master page.

When the user account is clicked, I record the Username in a Session Variable and then call that on page load with a `button postback url`. For example;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["QueryString"] != null)
    {
        AdminHiddenButtonDelete.PostBackUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath + Session["QueryString"].ToString();
    }
}
```

I'm setting the `Session["QueryString"]` when a button event is fired.

```
private void DeleteUser(string user)
{
    admin_user_accounts_wrapper.Style.Add("display", "none");
    admin_user_accounts_user_delete.Style.Add("display", "block");

    Session["ClickedUserAccount"] = user; // This session is used to hold the username of the clicked useraccount
    Session["QueryString"] = "?User = " + user + " ";

    admin_user_account_user_delete_heading.InnerText = "Are you sure you wish to delete the user account " + user + "?";
}
```

This is called when the user clicks the html `<button />` on the website.

Where query string houses the user accounts name. The outputted URL should then be `url.aspx?User=John` for example. Except, it always seems to be one postback behind. So, if I navigate to the `John` user, and then to the `Rick` user, the `Rick` `URL` will state `John`, and when I go back to the `John` user the `URL` will show `Rick`.

I hope this makes sense! I'm just not entirely sure on the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Where are you setting `Session["QueryString"]`? Can you update to include that code?

Comment: Of course. give me a second

Comment: It sounds like the following may be happening: 1. User clicks on Delete button to delete John. 2. The page load event is called, This updates the session variables with the John. 3. John gets deleted. 4. The Delete button's link gets updated with John, but that user has already been deleted.    Hence you're getting one user back.

Comment: It isn't more the user coming back, it just seems to be showing the parameter on the URL one refresh behind. Like the session variable is being updated a step behind when the user actually clicks the button, which is confusing.

Comment: Yep, my steps above may not be entirely accurate but it seems the code is deleting a user, then the session variables gets update with the deleted user instead of the next user. You should step through your code end-to-end to track what's happening exactly and in what order.

Comment: I haven't enabled the user delete yet, but that is what will happen, which is strange. Trying some things now which may rectify the issue.

Comment: I've stopped using sessions to see what happens. Seems to be two page refreshes which is causing this issue. I think I know what I need to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who may of done something similar to me I want to post my answer on how I fixed this in hopes it may help other people out there.

The first thing I did was go back to some sort of basics about dynamic content, and realised I should be using an AJAX `Update Panel` to decrease the amount of postbacks that was happening.

The next thing I did was go through all my code line by line. I programmatically made a content container that houses for `div` id's and also some HTML buttons. These HTML buttons when clicked fired a JavaScript function. This function then called two hidden `<asp` buttons. That is where my mistake started.

The JavaScript function called a click event;

```
 var hiddenButton = $('#<%= AdminHiddenButtonDelete.ClientID %>');
            if (hiddenButton != null) {
                hiddenButton.click();
```

This was my first mistake. I had now gotten two buttons, with one button doing a `click` server command twice, two post backs.

So, after removing the two hidden buttons and all the javascript I then needed to change the way I coded the content.

I swapped to using `WebControls.Button` and putting the contentResolver in the aspx.cs rather then its own class, then on click using `new EventHandler(this.UserDelete_Click);`

This tied the eventClick to my own function, allowing me to register the onClick event without postpacking as I'm using update panels.